# Prevent MATE from launching Caja Desktop when running i3

Tags: mate-desktop, i3, caja

A while back I installed i3 on my MATE box, and I'm quite happy with it, however despite disabling Caja Desktop (`x-caja-desktop`) when setting i3 as the default window manager through dconf editor, every time I install a .deb package via the gui installer, the desktop "window" opens and overlays my entire screen.

This is incredibly annoying, and hitting `super-shift-q` to close the window doesn't work, which forces me to just move it to an unused workspace.

Is there anything I can do to stop this from happening without installing a different file manager?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: @user44400 nope, I have not

Comment: Despite that, do you still use mate with i3?

Comment: Yeah I like the menu bar

Answer (score 0):

Try to set: `dconf key org.mate.background.show-desktop-icons` to: `false`

Comment: I don't have a background entry under `org.mate`

Comment: I do not have it either.

Comment: For Ubuntu Mate 18.04, it should be `org.mate.desktop.background.show-desktop-icons` (notice "desktop" after "mate"). See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu Mate 18.04:

Open a terminal and run the following command:

```
dconf write /org/mate/desktop/background/show-desktop-icons false
```

**Tip**: if you want to force to close the window which overlay your desktop or any windows, you can open a terminal and run the following command:

```
xkill
```

Then, click anywhere on the window you want to close and it should close.

Answer (score 0):

You can start Caja with the `--no-desktop` option to prevent it from opening the desktop.

Answer (score -1):

In the console, type:

```
dconf key org.mate.background.show-desktop-icons false
```

This change is persistent, i.e. it will not be undone on reboot.